Connect two tables with SUBSTR function
I want to have a complex SUBSTR in where clause, but got the error.

ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB

Is there any alernative solution to write this script?
 SELECT *
 FROM SVC_TREA,
      SAT_ORDR O
 WHERE O.NUM_UAT = SUBSTR(SVC_TREA.JSO_RQS, INSTR(SVC_TREA.JSO_RQS,'code',1,1) + 9,14)  

This is the only link between these two tables within my knowledge.

Column data types?

Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit JOIN syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed

It works with to_char on both sides. thanks a lot

You can use LIKE:
SELECT *
FROM   SVC_TREA t
       INNER JOIN SAT_ORDR o
       ON t.JSO_RQS LIKE '%code_____' || TO_CHAR(O.NUM_UAT, 'FM00000000000000') || '%'

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE SVC_TREA (JSO_RQS) AS
SELECT EMPTY_CLOB() || 'codeABCDE01234567890123' FROM DUAL

CREATE TABLE SAT_ORDR (num_uat) AS
SELECT 01234567890123 FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



JSO_RQS
NUM_UAT




codeABCDE01234567890123
1234567890123



fiddle
